# How to rewrite an url which has two variables and redirect them to the SEO friendly url and remove the spaces

Tags: php, .htaccess

One of my page url is `example.com/platform/bidProject.php?pID=JCVGK&name=Proof%20Reading%20Blogs`

I am trying to get this as : `example.com/platform/project-bids/JCVGK/Proof-Reading-Blogs/`

- project-bid is substitution
- JCVGK is ID
- Proof-Reading-Blogs is title

I have this in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} platform/([0-9]+)/([a-z\-A-Z]+)
RewriteRule (.*) bidProject.php?pID=%1&name=%2 [L]
```

but it seems it does not even work like `example.com/platform/project-bids/JCVGK/Proof%20Reading%20Blogs`

how can I solve this?

Comment: @anubhava `example.com/.htacsess`

Comment: @anubhava I've mentioned clearly here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394524/how-to-rewrite-two-parameters-url-to-seo-friendly-url-and-redirect-to-seo-friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^platform/project-bids/(.*)/(.*)/?$ platform/bidProject.php?pID=$1&name=$2 [L,NC]

# otherwise, serve your index.php app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This is just a general example. You may need to make certain modification according to your case. Such as it is assumed that the default page to serve is index.php. If the ID is for sure to be in capital letter, then it can be improved, replace the first (.*) with `([A-Z]+)`. There are many possibilities.

something similar to the code below should reload the page in new URL if the user visit the page with the URL in old pattern

```
<script>
  var curURL = window.location.href;
  if(curURL.indexOf('bidProject.php?pID=') > 0) {
    curURL = curURL.replace('bidProject.php?pID=', 'project-bids/');
    curURL = curURL.replace('&name=', '/');
    location.replace(curURL);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: this helps. thanks... anyhow if I go to `example.com/platform/bidProject.php?pID=JCVGK&name=Proof%20Reading%20Blogs` it stays still. I want this to be redirected to `example.com/platform/project-bids/JCVGK/Proof-Reading-Blogs/` if someone visits to `example.com/platform/bidProject.php?pID=JCVGK&name=Proof%20Reading%20Blogs`

Comment: @Riffaz Starr htaccess cannot do that, to my knowledge. However, you may use Javascript to do that.

Comment: @ildflue any sample tutorials ??

Comment: @Riffaz Starr I updated my answer with possible code example to be used for your purpose: if user visit the page through `example.com/platform/bidProject.php?pID=JCVGK&name=Proof%20R‌​eading%20Blogs` it will reload the page with new URL `example.com/platform/project-bids/JCVGK/Proof-Reading-Blogs`