# how to Rewrite two parameters URL to SEO friendly URL and Redirect to SEO friendly url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

This is my page url `example.com/platform/bidProject.php?pID=JCVGK&name=Proof%20Reading%20Blogs`

These rules helped me to Rewrite this as `example.com/platform/project-bids/JCVGK/Proof-Reading-Blogs/`

```
RewriteRule ^platform/project-bids/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /platform/bidProject.php?pID=$1&name=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/platform/bidProject.php?pID=$1&name=$2 
RewriteRule ^platform/bidProject.php?pID=$1&name=$2 /platform/project-bids/(.*)/(.*)/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

but the issue is if I visit to the page `example.com/platform/bidProject.php?pID=JCVGK&name=Proof%20Reading%20Blogs` the url stays same. I want this to be redirected to `example.com/platform/project-bids/JCVGK/Proof-Reading-Blogs/`

So I tired this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^(\S+)$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /platform/bidProject.php?pID=$1&v=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Seems I am doing something wrong with this because it makes no any affect on this.

I found a solution to redirect using JavaScript but I like to have .htaccess solution because JavaScript can be disable and can be seen in the source code. The basic intention for doing this fails here.

How can I achieve this using `.htaccess`

My htaccess path is `example.com/.htacsess`

Answer (score 0):

You can use these Rules

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirects /platform/bidProject.php. php?pid=val1&name=val2 to /platform/project-bids/val1/val2/
#redirects the old url to the new one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/platform/bidProject.php\?pID=([^&]+)&name=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /platform/project-bids/%1/%2/? [NC,R,L]
# rewrites or internally maps the new url to the old one
RewriteRule ^platform/project-bids/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /platform/bidProject.php?pID=$1&name=$2 [L,NC]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=([^&]+)&name=([^&]+)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^platform/bidProject.php$ /platform/project-bids/%1/%2/? [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^platform/project-bids/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /platform/bidProject.php?pID=$1&name=$2 [L,NC]
```

Change `R` to `R=301` (permanent redirect) when you are sure the rule is working ok.

Comment: `example.com/platform/bidProject.php?pID=JCVGK&name=Proof%20Reading%20Blogs` is redirected to `example.com/platform/project-bids/JCVGK/Proof%20Reading%20Blogs/` (no dashes) and I think `PHP GET` also does not work

Comment: I am using `$_GET['pID'];` to display it in the page but it does not work when the redirection.. but it works if I directly visit to `example.com/platform/project-bids/JCVGK/Proof-Reading-Bl‌​ogs/`

Comment: Is `Proof%20Reading%20Blogs` a dynamic part or does it change ?

Comment: that comes from database.. changes according to project id